# How to split command output in Windows command prompt?

Tags: cmd

Is there a `split` command in Windows, to split command output? My command is:

```
ipconfig | findstr /i "Default gateway" | findstr [0-9]
```

and the output is:

```
Default Gateway...: x.x.x.x
```

I need a single command, and the output should be only `x.x.x.x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is not exactly a split function, but you can use `FOR` to accomplish what you want :

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i  in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /i "Default gateway" ^| findstr [0-9]') do echo %%i
```

Comment: Really I want single line command like this. Thank you. However when I execute this in cmd prompt it says " %%i was unexpected at this time"

Comment: I fixed the error. instead of %%i we need to use %i. This resolves my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: use `%%i` in batch but `%i` in interractive mode

Comment: I used this to omit the space at the beginning. Perhaps there is a simpler way: for /f "tokens=12 delims=: " %i  in ('ipconfig ^| findst
r /i "Default gateway" ^| findstr [0-9]') do echo %i

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, there are two gateways returned, one for IPv4 and one for IPv6.  The `findstr` doesn't distinguish between them.  However, for me IPv4 is returned before IPv6.  This batch file extracts the IP address for the gateway from the `findstr` output:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('ipconfig ^| findstr "Default gateway"') do (
  if not defined _ip set _ip=%%i
)
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in ("!_ip!") do (
  set _ip=%%i
)

echo !_ip!

endlocal & set yourvar=%_ip%
```

I split it into two separate `for` commands (instead of nesting the `for` commands) so that I could just grab the first 'gateway' returned from the `findstr`.  The result has a leading space, so the 2nd `for` command removes the leading space.  The `& set yourvar=%_ip%` at the end is how you pass a `local` variable outside of the `local` block, but you don't have to use that...

Comment: I need a command(in a single line) instead of script. That will be more helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

You could define a subroutine within your command script that you could then call as a one-liner in another part of your command script.
I.E.

```
SETLOCAL
CALL :GETTIME
ECHO %HHMM%
GOTO :EXITPROG

:GETTIME
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims= " %%s IN (`TIME /T`) DO ( SET HHMM=%%s )
EXIT /b

:EXITPROG
ENDLOCAL
ECHO END OF PROGRAM
```